# Reload screen when data change - react native app

Tags: react-native, tabbar

I have two tabbar : ListMusic | Favourite.

When I add a song to favourite in tab ListMusic, how can I set listener for tab Favourite know that it need for reload to display new data.

Thanks!

Comment: Without you providing code is quite difficult. But do you have a state that holds the favourite list? If yes, then its a matter of letting the appropriate components know about the data change. I assume you are loading a list  on the favourites tab, when an item is added to a list it forces a reload of data (if setup correctly)

Comment: Component A (Tab ListMusic) contain list music, 
Component B (Tab favourite) contain list favoruite music from database).
When I tap favourite in A, in B should be reload.

Comment: @funkysoul: I using Redux for resolve this issues. Thanks for your comment. :) (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set one prop state which will be set on each change of ListMusic and use that prop in Favourite as `key` in `render()` 's parent view component. So, whenever state changes it will re-render Favourite.

Example:

```
render() {
    const unconfirmedErrorMsgToken = this.props.unconfirmedErrorMsgToken;
    return (
      <View key={this.state.ListMusicSuccess} >
        ...
      </View>
    );
}
```