# How to update state of ListView item in parent screen when using react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have two screens:

Screen A(Parent screen): 
Using ListView to show the list of post. Each row has a Like button to like or dislike the post.

Screen B(PostDetail): 
When tap on a ListView item, I will navigate to this screen. It also has a Like button to like or dislike the post.

Problem: When I update like state on the detail screen and I also want this is updated to that post on the parent screen when tap on Back button(The button generated from Stack Navigation). How to do that?

Comment: please add your code :)

Comment: please add your update like state code in able to help you.

Comment: check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45027513/reload-screen-when-data-change-react-native-app/45027888#45027888